# How to join to the nearest (lower date)

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have 2 tables.

The first one is called MachineTimes. This table is not updated daily, and it gives you a value (CumulativeTimes) that is how many hours that machine has been used up to that point.

[image]

I've got a second table called (SessionList) that contains SerialNumbers, SessionIds, and StartTimes for those Sessions.

[image]

What I want to do is join both tables on the TimeStamp and the StartTime together, but I want to match to the closest (lower) TimeStamp available.

Giving me this type of table as a result.

[image]

So far, I have used this approach, where if there is a match on the exact day then it gives me the correct CumulativeTimes, but otherwise it gives me blanks which is what I am trying to avoid.

```
let CumulativeTimes_Query = MachineTimes
| extend StartTime2 = format_datetime(TimeStamp,'yy-MM-dd');
let age_of_machine = SessionList
| distinct SerialNumber, SessionId, StartTime2 = format_datetime(TimeStamp,'yy-MM-dd')
| join kind=inner CumulativeTimes_Query on StartTime2, SerialNumber
| project SerialNumber, SessionId, CumulativeTimes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining `MachineTimes` and `SessionList` tables basis the fields  `StartTime2` and  `SerialNumber`, you can join based on `SerialNumber` field only. Then find the difference between `Timestamp` field and `StartTime` date field for every row. Then from the resultant data, group by  `SerialNumber`, `SessionId` and take the minimum value of `difference` field. Below is the code.

```
let MachineTimes = datatable(SerialNumber:string, TimeStamp:datetime  , CumulativeTimes:string )
[
'ABC-1','2023-04-17','709.8082847',
'ABC-1','2023-04-14','709.7787561',
'ABC-2','2021-07-12','45.164978',
'ABC-2','2021-07-08','45.162995',
'ABC-2','2021-07-07','45.152477',
'ABC-2','2021-06-08','45.103493',
'ABC-2','2021-04-29','1.304171',
'ABC-3','2021-10-19','1.523642',
'ABC-3','2021-10-14','1.520901',
'ABC-3','2021-09-23','1.514814',
'ABC-3','2021-09-22','1.512814',
'ABC-3','2021-07-06','0.469807',
];
let SessionList = datatable(SerialNumber:string, SessionId:string, StartTime:datetime )
[
'ABC-1','ABC1-123','2023-04-17',
'ABC-1','ABC1-124','2023-04-15',
'ABC-1','ABC1-125','2023-04-14',
'ABC-2','ABC2-123','2021-06-13',
'ABC-2','ABC2-124','2021-06-08',
'ABC-3','ABC3-123','2021-10-20',
];
let CumulativeTimes_Query = MachineTimes;
let age_of_machine = SessionList
| join kind=inner CumulativeTimes_Query on  SerialNumber
| extend difference=abs(datetime_diff('day',TimeStamp,StartTime))
| summarize arg_min(difference, *) by SerialNumber, SessionId
| project SerialNumber, SessionId, CumulativeTimes
| order by SerialNumber asc ;
age_of_machine
```

**Output**

| SerialNumber | SessionId | CumulativeTimes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC-1 | ABC1-125 | 709.7787561 |
| ABC-1 | ABC1-124 | 709.7787561 |
| ABC-1 | ABC1-123 | 709.8082847 |
| ABC-2 | ABC2-124 | 45.103493 |
| ABC-2 | ABC2-123 | 45.103493 |
| ABC-3 | ABC3-123 | 1.523642 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)